# How to simplify/reuse this exception handling code

Tags: java, exception, code-reuse

I tend to write code like the following a lot:

```
BufferedWriter w = null; // Or any other object that throws exceptions and needs to be closed
try {
    w = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    // Do something with w
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (w != null) {
        try {
            w.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It usually involves an object that throws exceptions and needs to be closed, and that closing it may also throw an exception.

I was wondering if the above code can be simplified or reused in any way.

Comment: I'm learning a lot of Java thanks to this question. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually put contents of your `finally` block in a helper. Like this

```
void close(Closeable c) {
    if (c != null) {
        try {
            c.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // perform logging or just ignore error
        }
    }
}
```

`Closeable` interface is implemented by many classes (input streams, database connections, etc), so this is kinda general-purpose helper.

Comment: Oh! Something like Closeable is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to write code for closing in finally block, you should have a look at [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/Cleanup.html)

Instead of writing the normal

```
public class CleanupExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  InputStream in = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
  try {
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(args[1]);
    try {
      byte[] b = new byte[10000];
      while (true) {
         int r = in.read(b);
         if (r == -1) break;
         out.write(b, 0, r);
      }
    } finally {
        out.close();
      }
  } finally {
     in.close();
    }
  }
}
```

With Lombok you can write

```
public class CleanupExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    @Cleanup InputStream in = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
    @Cleanup OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(args[1]);
    byte[] b = new byte[10000];
    while (true) {
      int r = in.read(b);
      if (r == -1) break;
      out.write(b, 0, r);
    }
   }
 }
```

Much more readable, and it generates the correct way of closing the Stream. This works with all the `Closeable` interfaces

Answer (score 4):

Yes, since java 1.5 there is a Closeable interface.   You can have a static method that closes any Closeable type.

```
  public static void closeIO(Closeable closeable){
      if (closeable != null) {
        try {
            closeable.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or reuse `Closeables` from Guava.

Answer (score 3):

Java 7 is having try with resource support. Check [this](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/java-7-gets-try-with-resources-support-automatic-resource-management/) out for more information.

I am quoting the relevant text and a code example here:

with the new try-with-resource language feature in Java 7, you effectively declare your stream arguments as part of the try-construct, and the compiler generates code that manages those resources automatically and cleanly for you.

```
private static void customBufferStreamCopy(File source, File target) {
    try (InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(source);
        OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(target)){

        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];

        int i;
        while ((i = fis.read(buf)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buf, 0, i);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but maybe he doesn't want to wait mid-2011 to use JDK 1.7, no?

Comment: I'm sure any client would understand. :P

Answer (score 1):

I tend to agree with others who offer a method taking a `Closeable`, but due to maintining very long lived programs, the solution I use is slightly different.  Basically it takes an `OutputStream` to provide flexibility.

```
public class IOHandler {

  private IOHandler();

  public static void close(OutputStream out, Closeable c) {
    if (c != null) {
      try {
        c.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        out.print(c.printStackTrace().getBytes());
    }
  }

}
```

The main advantages of this is that you can call it in a variety of ways, removing the need for specialized utilities to handle logging exceptions to stderr, stdout, and files.

```
IOHandler.close(System.out, openFile);
IOHandler.close(System.err, openFile);
IOHandler.close(logFile, openFile);
```

Other than this one added feature, it's basically the same solution others have offered.

Answer (score 1):

I find it is usually best not to have try catch and finally all in the same block. It is often better to have a try-catch block and a separate try-finally block.

```
try {
    BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file)); // Or any other object that throws exceptions and needs to be closed
    try {
        // Do something with w
    } finally {
        w.close();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This also avoids any need to null check w.

Comment: You'll get problems when underlying streams are still created but outer streams throwing an exception in constructor. Then the underlying streams are not closed.

Comment: @Fatal `new BufferedWriter(Writer)` does not throw any checked exceptions. Even if it did, the problem exists in the call `new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))` as described by the question, not by this method of handling the exception. To mitigate, you have to assign the `new FileWriter` to a separate variable and close it as well.

Comment: You're right with BufferedWriter, but this topic here is more general and your advice is very general, too. You do not have to assign and close FileWriter seperatly, because of `close()` contract. hgpc is doing it right in his opening post. And that's the way it is done in all common libs like Apache Commons I know - and not for accident. So accepted answer is the best - it just improves the way doing it right and reduces boilerplate. This here is nothing I would recommend even when it might work in this special case here.

Comment: @Fatal I don't understand what you are saying. Aside from being able to do different things in the two catch clauses, the two approaches are functionally identical. Are you saying they are not (if so how?), or are you saying that the common way is cleaner?

Comment: They are not identical when constructor may throw an exception and therefore your way is not the way I would recommend. It is error-prone.

Comment: @Fatal Yes they are. Your way: the outer constructor throws an exception, `w` remains `null`. Null check skips `w.close()`.
My way: the outer constructor throws an exception, exception code skips `w.close()`. The close is not called either way.

Comment: @Fatal let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2748/discussion-between-ilmtitan-and-fatal)

Answer (score 0):

Write it in a method ...

```
BuffereWriter getMyWriter()
{

// your code....

return w;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A template method pattern can be applied here:

```
public class FileTemplate {
    public void write(File file, WriteCallback c) {
        BufferedWriter w = null; // Or any other object that throws exceptions and needs to be closed 
        try { 
            w = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file)); 
            c.writeFile(w); 
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } finally { 
            if (w != null) { 
                try { 
                    w.close(); 
                } catch (IOException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                } 
            } 
        }
    }
}

public interface WriteCallback {
    public void writeFile(BufferedWriter w) throws IOException;
}
```

.

```
new FileTemplate().write(file, new WriteCallback() {
    public void writeFile(BufferedWriter w) { ... }
});
```