# How close Java Input Streams?

Tags: java, io, stream

In the following code:

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(
          new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
in.close();
```

Do I need to close the 2 other stream in addition to closing the "top level" stream?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you look the source of `DataInputStream` you can see that it closes the underlying streams as well. so you don't need. and this is (or should be) true for all type of streams.

Comment: More to the point, it's documented. It's a bit fragmented, but `DataInputStream` inherits `close` from `FilterInputStream`, which documents that it calls `close` on the underlying `InputStream`: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html So you know that the behavior isn't just a side-effect of a particular implementation.

Comment: Actually its true for all types of `Closeable`

Comment: @Sherwin ... provided that they implement the "contract" properly :-)

Answer (score 3):

I will use this opportunity to answer with an answer I have already made before.

By using [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org) you can let Lombok correctly close the streams for you.
Details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907281/how-to-simplify-reuse-this-exception-handling-code/3907789#3907789).

Answer (score 1):

Karazi, is right in suggesting that. Further, just to get an idea and a little more insight, Java IO API is actually implemented using decorator pattern. You can check out [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) on wiki.

Answer (score 1):

I'd stick the close in a finally block just to make sure it is flushed properly in case of an exception.

```
public void tryToDoWhatever() throws Exception
{
    DataInputStream in = null;
    try
    {
         in = new DataInputStream(
              new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
    }
    finally
    { 
        if (in != null)
            in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right but this raise a new question: How handle the IOException that can be thrown by in.close ?? Add try catch in finally block or forward it at upper level ?

Comment: Yes that's not quite hopw I normally do it

Comment: @Manuel Selva - I always separate the exception handling from the business logic. I would have a method called 'doWhatever()' which calls tryToDoWhatever in a try/catch block to deal with the exceptions in there

Comment: **DO NOT** throw `Exception` from this method. Throw `IOException` instead